# Have a popupmenu appear on a popupmenu on right-click

Tags: python, wxpython, right-click, wxwidgets, popupmenu

I have a wx Popupmenu appear when I left-click on a toolbar `LabelTool`. I already have a binding to have a handler run when I left click an item in the menu, but I want another popup menu to appear when I right click an item in the original popup menu. I've already tried binding it to `wx.EVT_RIGHT_DOWN` but it doesn't do it. Whenever I try right clicking on a menu object, it seems it still calls the `wx.EVT_MENU`, which calls the same handler as a left-click would. How would I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, that is not supported. Besides, no user is going to expect that they need to right click on a context menu anyway. You should rethink your design so it's more intuitive. Perhaps by using a sub-menu instead of a secondary popup menu